# When assigning the value of a MEMPTR to a LONGCHAR variable using GET-STRING, i got an error 9324

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, 4gl

When assigning the value of a MEMPTR to a LONGCHAR variable using GET-STRING, i got an error 9324 (Attempt to exceed maximum size of a CHARACTER variable) is there any solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Copy MEMPTR to/from a LONGCHAR variable with out getting error or NULL value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065947/how-to-copy-memptr-to-from-a-longchar-variable-with-out-getting-error-or-null-va)

Answer (score 0):

You should use COPY-LOB statement

Answer (score -1):

As definitely not solved (COPY-LOB does not work) use the following hard coding:

```
DEF VAR Z64 AS MEMPTR.
DEF VAR A AS LONGCHAR.
DEF VAR Z AS CHAR.

DEF VAR size64  AS INT.
SET-SIZE(Z64) = 200000.  /* base64 is a function of vpxPrint */
  RUN base64("e:/temp/XXXX.jpg", Z64, 10, OUTPUT size64). /* get the size */
MESSAGE "base64 string length" size64 VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
  RUN base64("e:/temp/XXXX.jpg", Z64, 200000, OUTPUT size64).

DEF VAR i AS INT.
DEF VAR j AS INT.
DEF VAR lastSegment AS INT.

/* Segments of 30.000 bytes (PROGRESS limit)  */

j = TRUNC(size64 / 30000, 0).
IF j MOD 30000 <> 0 THEN DO:
        j = j + 1.
        lastSegment = size64 MOD 30000.
        END.
ELSE
        lastSegment = 30000.

DO i = 1 TO j:                                      
                    Z = GET-STRING(Z64, (i - 1) * 30000 + 1, 
                                   (IF i = j THEN lastSegment ELSE 30000)).                     
                    A = A + Z.
                    END.

SET-SIZE(z64) = 0.

/* LONGCHAR "A"   contains the string!
   ===================================*/
```